# How do I avoid my buttons from clashing on one stylesheet?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, routes

Trying to style my button from a different component that I routed from App.js but it takes the same css style from index.css, I just want to avoid the clash from index.css. I've tried css modules but that didn't seem to work. Now I'm wondering if installing bootstrap is a solution.  **My Code:** https://codesandbox.io/s/gamer-2-0-vgmm0

Comment: I would absolutely recommend Bootstrap to ANYBODY who likes to write code but with the grunt work done. In Bootstrap you don't even really need extra CSS or JS anymore except to fine tune and customise.

Comment: Would that help resolve style clashing? This problem is preventing me from finishing my two projects.

Comment: Comments are not meant for discussion and chat so please do not think I am being rude. Fairly certain that when you ask questions, as long as there is enough info to work with, you will always get answers.  Generally with CSS styling, if you can find the item that is directing the style then it can be changed or over-ridden. Try using the console view in your browser to examine the page.

Comment: I know I shouldn't be discussing but console view doesn't really help me here. It says that the stylesheet is coming from index.css but I'm trying to style the other buttons that are rendered on button click.

Comment: Discussion is OK if it relates to the quedtion that has been asked. It sounds as if in the `<head>` of your page there is some styling which is probably inside `<style>` tags. Perhaps there is a conflict here with some other CSS?

Comment: I would say give Bootstrap a go. It's really worth it. The only thing is to apply it half way tthrough a website build will mean updating a lot of your HTML to accommodate the Bootstrap way of doing things. This will usually just involve adding a few `class=""`

Comment: I found a solution by changing my css file to "my-file.module.css" and it worked! Now I have kind of a noob question, how would I put different background images for each product? Right now when insert a background image into css it's like a one for all thing.